Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FlowLayoutPanel'
I faced this error:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FlowLayoutPanel'

while adding controlbox to flowlayoutpanel
my issue in this line
FlowLayoutPanel1.Invoke(Sub() FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(box))

Edit: The controlbox is added just once, my loop its Purpose is add many controlboxes based on mt sql table
this is my full code
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-AVL3TKN;Initial Catalog=SimpleSaleDB;Integrated Security=true;"
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Try
                connection.Open()
                Dim query As String = "Select Itm_id,Itm_name,Itm_barcode,Cat_name,Unit_name,Store_name,Itm_quantity,Itm_buy,Itm_sale,Itm_note,Itm_tax,Itm_end,Itm_expire,Itm_date,User_fname,currency From ItemsTBL,CategoryTBL,UnitsTBL,StoresTBL,UsersTBL Where  ItemsTBL.Cat_id = CategoryTBL.Cat_id and ItemsTBL.Unit_id = UnitsTBL.Unit_id and ItemsTBL.Store_id = StoresTBL.Store_id and ItemsTBL.User_id = UsersTBL.User_id and Itm_id > (Select Max(Itm_id) - " & RowsNumber & " From ItemsTBL) order by Itm_id desc"
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim box As New ProductBox()
                    box.TableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
                    box.NameLBL.Text = reader("Itm_name").ToString()
                    box.NameLBL.Tag = reader("Itm_id").ToString()
                    box.QuantityLBL.Text = reader("Itm_quantity").ToString() + " " + reader("Unit_name")
                    Dim buy As Double = reader("Itm_buy")
                    Dim sale As Double = reader("Itm_sale")
                    box.BuyLBL.Text = buy.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-IQ"))
                    box.SaleLBL.Text = sale.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-IQ"))
                        FlowLayoutPanel1.Invoke(Sub() FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(box))
                    box.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No
                    box.TableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout()
                End While
                reader.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to the database: " & ex.Message)
            Finally
                connection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
        SalsePercentage()
    End Sub


Whatever ProductBox is, you have to create it in the UI Thread. Pass the data you need to the ProgressChanged event handler, when calling ReportProgress() (the event is raised in the calling Thread) -- You should also avoid setting the child Controls' Access Modifier to Public. Use the Constructor or specialized public methods / properties for that

Btw, do not invoke from the DoWork event handler, always use the provided ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events. Or move to Tasks, the Progress delegate allows to handle these situations quite easily

This question is similar to: BackgroundWorker - Cross-thread operation not valid. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
